Adding multiple choropleth layers on a folium map as radio buttons
I am trying to create an interactive folium map in python and save as a html file. I want to add OpenStreetMap as basemap and add 2 choropleth layers onto the map. This is what it looks like so far:
First i prepare all the variables needed for the choropleth maps (choro_data and geo_data). Then i create the to choropleths. The variable overlay = False turns the layers from checkboxes to radio buttons so that it is just possible to show either one of them. My problem is, that now also the OpenStreetMap basemap is not shown - just when I select it.
Is there a way to display the basemap by default and add two choropleth maps as radio buttons to the map?
import geopandas as gpd
import os
import json
import folium

# Importing Geodatafile for Choropleth
polygons = gpd.read_file("MyGeoDataFrame.gpkg")

# Extracting center for Map
center = polygons.unary_union.convex_hull.centroid

m = folium.Map(location=[center.y, center.x], zoom_start=10, tiles = "OpenStreetMap")

#  Create choro_data for folium, has to be "dict"
choro_data = polygons['Car'].to_dict()

# Create GeoData for folium, has to be "geojson"
polygons["index_right"] = range(0,len(polygons))
geojson = json.loads(polygons.to_json())
for feature in geojson['features']:
    feature['id'] = feature['properties']['index_right']


# Adding first Choropleth with Car
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geojson,
    name="Car",
    data=choro_data,
    key_on="id",
    fill_color="RdYlGn",
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_weight=0.4,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Time to schools [min] by car",
    overlay = False
).add_to(m)


#  Update choro_data (second layer) for folium, has to be "dict"
choro_data = polygons['Bike'].to_dict()


# Adding second Choropleth with Bike
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geojson,
    name="Bike",
    data=choro_data,
    key_on="id",
    fill_color="RdYlGn",
    fill_opacity=1,
    line_weight=0.4,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Time to schools [km] by bike",
    overlay = False
).add_to(m)


# Layer Control
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

# Export HTML
m.save("Map.html")




